# Is there STB emulator for STB developers which runs on PC?

Tags: android-emulator, emulators, development

We develop an STB app, we run it on actual STB boxes for testing, the boxes are slow and the development experience is so bad.

Many options on the STB are only accessible through a remote control. We use windows 10. We tried many Android emulators and bluestacks and whatnot, all of them boot the app but they boot it in phone layout, we're looking for

1. Free STB emulator that can be used for development and run on windows
2. The STB should open the app in STB layout, as if we're using an
   actual STB BOX
3. The STB should map some keyboard keys as if they were TV remote control keys, such that everything we can do on an STB, can be done on the emulator

Comment: The emulator form Android SDK has two Android TV emulator device profiles, have you tried them?

Comment: @Robert I'm not the android developer, I asked him to test that, he said he did and didn't work, not sure if I should take his word, will test that myself in few days and let you know